I need to send an http request from Laravel 10 to cPanel UAPI to create a new email
According to the cPanel documentation:

To call a UAPI function with an API token, run the following command from the command line:
curl -H'Authorization: cpanel username:APITOKEN' 'https://example.com:2083/execute/Module/function?parameter=value'




Item
Description
Example




username
The cPanel account's username.
username


APITOKEN
The API token.
U7HMR63FGY292DQZ4H5BFH16JLYMO01M


example.com
Your cPanel server's domain
example.com


Module
The API module name.
Email


function
The API function's name.
add_pop


parameter
The function's input parameters.
email


value
The value to assign to the input parameter.
12345luggage



For example, your command may resemble the following example:
curl -H'Authorization: cpanel username:U7HMR63FHY282DQZ4H5BIH16JLYSO01M' 'https://example.com:2083/execute/Email/add_pop?email=newuser&password=12345luggage'



source: https://api.docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/tokens/

I also created the following function in my controller:
public function test()
{
    $response = Http::post('https://example.com:2083' ,[
        'username' => 'holidays',
        'APITOKEN' => 'XPA6V9NSZ5JGKXU5VE2X214U53WROFI0',
        'Module' => 'Email',
        'function' => 'add_pop',
        'parameter' => 'email',
        'value' => 'test',
 
    ]);
    return $response;
    // dd($response);
}

How can I send a request correctly to cPanel to create a new email and get a successful message in Laravel 10?
Thank you

You need to use headers in Laravel HTTP.
So the correct code will be:
public function test()
{
    $response = Http::withHeaders('Authorization', 'cpanel holidays:XPA6V9NSZ5JGKXU5VE2X214U53WROFI0')
        ->post('https://example.com:2083' ,[
            'Module' => 'Email',
            'function' => 'add_pop',
            'parameter' => 'email',
            'value' => 'test',
        ]);
    return $response;
    // dd($response);
}

